# Odoo[12]: How to Add one or more Followers automatically from Drop-down field

Tags: addition, odoo-12

I Inherited the `crm.lead` model and I created the one drop-down custom field in this field display only group assign users. now I want to do that when I select which users from the Dropdown list these users go and add automatically in the Followers.

How to do this. If you know about it please let me know.

See My Code.

.py File

```py
estimation_id = fields.Many2many('res.users', default=lambda self:self.env.user, domain=lambda self: [("groups_id", "=", self.env.ref( "estimation.group_user_hide" ).id)], select=True, track_visibility='onchange', string='Estimation Asign To')
```

Comment: i found the solution but only for the new records. how to generate write method for the update the records. see the  Create()

Comment: @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        lead_res = super(CrmLead, self).create(vals)
        for rec in lead_res:
            if rec.estimation_id:
                partner_ids = []
                for est_rec in rec.estimation_id:
                    if est_rec.partner_id and est_rec.partner_id.email:
                        partner_ids.append(est_rec.partner_id.id)
                if partner_ids:
                    rec.message_subscribe(partner_ids, None)
        return lead_res

Answer (score 0):

I have my own code of add Followers from the dropdown firld. problem is that i can't remove only single record from the FOllowers list. can you suggest where my code is wrong or what i'm missing ?

```
    @api.multi
    def write(self, vals):
        res = super(CrmLead, self).write(vals)
        for rec in self:
            if rec.estimation_id:
                partner_ids = []
                for est_rec in rec.estimation_id:
                    if est_rec.partner_id and est_rec.partner_id.email:
                        partner_ids.append(est_rec.partner_id.id)
                rec.message_subscribe(partner_ids, None)
                #message_unsubscribe
                message_partner_ids = rec.message_partner_ids.ids

                est_ids = [est_rec.partner_id.id for est_rec in rec.estimation_id] + [self.env.ref('base.partner_root').id]
                unsub_partners = set(message_partner_ids) - set(est_ids)
                template_obj = self.env['mail.mail']
                template_data = {
                                'subject': 'New Estimation Asign : ',
                                'body_html': "message_body",
                                'email_from': self.env['mail.message']._get_default_from(),
                                'email_to': est_rec.partner_id.email
                            }
                template_id = template_obj.create(template_data)
                template_obj.send(template_id)
                if list(unsub_partners):
                    rec.message_unsubscribe(list(unsub_partners))
        return res
```

Comment: @Charif Say something on above code where i'm wrong ?